# Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com

Tags: github, terminal, homebrew, github-pages

Whenever i run ant command in terminal.
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443 after 94 ms: Couldn't connect to server`

I keep getting this error. Please help. I’m new to this.
I already tried adding DNS 8.8.8.8. Nothing changed. Also VPN is disabled.

Answer (score -1):

That is generally github service issue, just wait some time and retry.